# Verify that point $ \ A(6,8,4) \ $ lies on the surface

Tags: calculus

A circle of radius $ \ 5  \ $ with center $ \ (13,0,0) \ $ that lies in the  $ \ xz-plane \ $ is rotated about the $ \ z-axis \ $ to form a surface. Verify that point  $ \ A(6,8,4) \ $ lies on the surface and then find an equation of the tangent plane to the surface at $ \ A \ $. Use implicit differentiation.

**Answer:**

An arbitrary point on the circle of radius $ \ 5 \ $  with center $ \ (13,0,0) \ $ is

$$ (x,z)=(13+5 \cos \theta, 5 \sin \theta) \ , \ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi $$

Thus rotating the circle about z-axis **creates a torus whose equations** are

$x= (13+5 \cos \theta) \cos \phi \\ y=(13+5 \cos \theta) \sin \phi \\ z=5 \sin \theta $

where $ \ 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi \ $

Now we have to show that the point $ \ A= (6,8,4) \ $ lie on the surface of the torus.

**But how to check this?**

help me

Comment: Hint: Any plane through the z-axis will have 2 circles of radius 5 in common with the torus. The midpoints of these circles will be on the circle created by rotating the point (13,0,0) around the z-axis. If you consider the plane through the z-axis and the point $A$, you now have a planar problem: Does the point $A$ lay on one of 2 circles with radius 5, whose midpoints you have to determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the torus consists of all points $(x,y,z)$ where $x= (13+5 \cos \theta) \cos \phi,$ $y=(13+5 \cos \theta) \sin \phi,$ and $z=5 \sin \theta$ for some $\phi$ and $\theta$.  So, you just have to show there exists $\phi$ and $\theta$ such that $$6= (13+5 \cos \theta) \cos \phi,$$ $$8=(13+5 \cos \theta) \sin \phi,$$ and $$4=5 \sin \theta.$$  I would suggest starting with the last equation since it is the simplest.  There definitely exists $\theta$ such that $4=5\sin\theta$, since $\sin$ takes all values between $-1$ and $1$.  Now, for such a $\theta$, what could $\cos\theta$ be?  Can you then find $\phi$ which makes the first two equations hold?

More details are hidden below.

> If $\sin\theta=4/5$, then $\cos\theta$ can be either $3/5$ or $-3/5$.  The first case does not work, but in the second case the first two equations become $6=10\cos\phi$ and $8=10\sin\phi$.  We can solve this by taking $\phi$ such that $\cos\phi=3/5$ and $\sin\phi=4/5$ (such a $\phi$ exists since $(3/5)^2+(4/5)^2=1$).

Comment: How to find the equation of tangent plane at $ \ A=(6,8,4) \ $ ? We have  $ r(\theta, \phi)=((13+5 \cos \theta) \cos \phi, (13+5 \sin \theta) \sin \phi, 5 \sin \theta) \ $. Now we have to find $ r_{\theta} , \ r_{\phi} \ $ at $ \ A=(6,8,4) \ $

Answer (score 1):

Let's check if there are $\theta$ and $\phi$ so that
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
(13+5\cos{\theta})\cos{\phi} &=& 6    \\
(13+5\cos{\theta})\sin{\phi} &=& 8    \\
5\sin{\theta} &=& 4 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
from the last equation we get $\sin{\theta} = \frac{4}{5} \Rightarrow \cos{\theta} = \pm\frac{3}{5}$. Using the positive result in the first two equations, we get
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
16\cos{\phi} &=& 6    \\
16\sin{\phi} &=& 8    \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now $\cos^2{\phi} + \sin^2{\phi} = \left(\frac{6}{16} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{8}{16} \right)^2 = \frac{25}{64} \neq 1$ and we have a clear problem. The negative root gives us
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
10\cos{\phi} &=& 6    \\
10\sin{\phi} &=& 8    \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and $\cos^2{\phi} + \sin^2{\phi} = \left(\frac{6}{10} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{8}{10} \right)^2 = 1$ which is ok.

Therefore, the answer is yes.

Comment: Yeah, I was too quick to write. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the circle is

- $(x-13)^2+z^2=25\implies x=\pm\sqrt{25-z^2}+13$

thus in the plane $y-x$ we have

- $x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{25-z^2}+13)^2$
- $x^2+y^2=(-\sqrt{25-z^2}+13)^2$

From here we can check whether $A$ belongs to the surface and find the tangent plane.